# How does Bev know she's leaving across the country after encountering IT

Tags: plot-explanation, it-2017

This is going to be heavy spoilers, but this regards the *It (2017)*  and the character Beverly. I think I might have missed something or it wasn't explained.

> In the movie, Beverly attacks and possibly kills her father near the end of the film.

She does this in the bathroom and then, as she turns to leave, Pennywise captures her and takes her away to the Barrens and shows her the deadlights.  Bill and company go on a quest to rescue Bev and to kill Pennywise. They go to the house on Neibolt street, and then into the sewer system,

> find Bev and kill Pennywise.

That's all well and good, but then...

> After killing Pennywise and leaving the sewers

the group all cut their hands and take a blood oath to come back if Pennywise shows up again. One by one the group leaves and soon it's just Bev and Bill. Bev says she's leaving for Seattle (I think); but, my question is, *how does she know this*?

She didn't make any plans, her father may or may not be dead, yet, *it seems like settled business that she's going across the country, if not the next day, so soon*.

Comment: Please hide only part that can be a spoiler and avoid using large yellow empty boxes that totally harms the readability. Also users who see the question will definitely hover over those yellow boxes. Thank you.

Comment: May be she is moving with a relative.

Comment: I saw the film earlier this week.  I believe she explicitly mentions that she is going to live with an uncle in Portland.  It is settled business - she's made the plans. I believe the hand cutting scene is set a few days after they leave the sewer - not immediately after.  Hopefully someone with a better memory will come in and give the exact quote!

Comment: I'm pretty sure the hand cutting scene was directly after because I recall seeing Stan's face and it was still cut up from the attack.

Comment: also, she was probably referring to Portland Maine, which is a couple of hours away from Derry, and not Portland Oregon, which would be all the way across the country.

Comment: I thought Stan's face had been bandaged up by the hand cutting scene.  And Portland, Maine makes more sense than Portland, Oregon.  I thought her moving across the country was hinting that they were all going to spread across the country between the first and second movies, but she probably meant Portland, Maine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Several Days Have Passed

It isn't clear in the film due to the way it is edited, but the scene is not taking place right after they exit the sewers but is on a later date, at the end of the summer most likely.

#### Some evidence to let us know this:

1. Stanley has bandages on his face from the teeth marks from IT.
2. The children are wearing different clothing (Bill is wearing a red
   plaid shirt instead of the blue and white baseball jersey, Ritchie
   is wearing a soccer jersey instead of his hawaiian shirt, Eddie is
   wearing a polo instead of his t-shirt, Bev is wearing overalls
   instead of a blouse, etc)
3. The kids are no longer covered in sewer scum. At the end of the sewer scene they are pretty dirty and covered in all kinds of grossness but in the meadow scene they are all cleaned up.

Given this information, there clearly has been enough time for Beverly to have found out that she is moving for reasons not revealed to us, but we can guess that it is related to whatever has happened to her father.

Comment: *Stanley has bandages on his face from the teeth marks from IT.* Did he? I don't recall that. You might be right and that would **definitely** be evidence that it occurred later, as would points 2 and 3 - although I don't recall a lot of sewer scum on them.  I might be seeing it again tomorrow, and if I do and you're correct, I'll give you the check mark. That is, unless you could get screen captures before then.

Comment: Yup he did. I just saw it before writing this answer so I'm confident you'll be able to confirm :)

Comment: Just FYI - I saw the movie again, it's definitely later - when the camera is far away it says 'September' and I believe the sewer attack happened in August.

Answer (score 2):

The whole story takes time over whole summer holidays:

1. First we have a screen saying **"June"** - kids leave the school; most of the movie takes place in this time until the Looser have an argue and split up.
2. Time passes, the screen says **"July"** - "Loosers" are spending time mostly separately, until events with Beverly force them to unite and fight the Pennywise.
3. At the beginning of the "cutting hands" scene, you can see the text saying **"August"** - this means that there again a few days have passed between the events in the sewers and the meeting near the river: we can see that their wounds have been patched, they wear different clothes etc. It would also give Beverly a plenty of time to organise her trip - she even says that she has been speaking with her relative (aunt I believe) and that she can stay there as long as she wants.